# Changing the material for each 3D game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing a color shop for my 3D game objects, I have four prefabs.

What I'm facing is the material got stuck only in one game object, but I need all of the game objects to be the same color once the player purchased the color.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] playerPanels;

    [HideInInspector]
    public bool gameIsOver = false;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ammoCount = 0;

    public void AddPlayerPanel(int index)       //Spawner script calls this function
    {
        if (FindObjectOfType<Spawner>().spawnedObstacles != 0)      //If this is not the first spawn
            Destroy(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PlayerPanel").gameObject, 0.45f);     //Then destroys the previously spawned playerPanel
        Instantiate(playerPanels[index], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);      //Spawns a new one
    }

    public void GreenColor()
    {
        Component[] renderers = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PlayerPanel").GetComponentsInChildren(typeof(Renderer));
        foreach (Renderer childRenderer in renderers)
        {
            childRenderer.material.color = Color.green;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? for example, debug this foreach loop and tell us how many items are iterating in this loop, if its only one, or if its more than one

Comment: The foreach loop it's for only one, this loop to get the game objects children's and to assign the material for each game object children